# How to interpret ADC values from L476RG ADC channel?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

it is L476RG, I read the reference manual, I tried to read a 3.2v dc signal, I use `HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED); 
int vdda=HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_GetValue(&hadc1,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1); 
HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100); 
int digital_result = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); 
HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);`

the vdda = 69 from the HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_GetValue function, digital_result=948; then I use formula float `real_volt=vdda/4095.0*digital_result`; I got a 15.9v result, where am I wrong? it is 12 bit ADC and single-ended.

Another interesting thing is, this is 12 bit ADC, but HAL_ADC_GetValue return a uint32_t, so sometimes this return value is very large, such as 65505 for a 2.4v input, there is no offset so the data should be no-sign, shall I directly extract the 12 bits on the right (right-aligned)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you read the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf) It tells you how to set the ADC reference voltage, and how to adjust the resolution (trading off conversion time).

Comment: To be fair, that's the most complicated ADC I've seen on a $6 microcontroller.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did not find this manual before, I am reading it, suppose I could set the reference voltage to 3.3v, then how to convert the digital values?

Comment: It depends how you set the resolution and over-sampling. Whether you choose left or right justification, etc.

Comment: Without the ADC settings this question is not answerable - we use the L451 which has the same ADC implementation (in my understanding) and the results are perfectly fine.

Comment: I read the reference manual, I tried to read a 3.2v dc signal, I use HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED); and int vdda=HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_GetValue(&hadc1,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
 so I then use 
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
  HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100);
  digital_result = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

the vdda = 69 from the HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_GetValue function, 
digital_result=948;
then I  use formula  
float real_volt=vdda/4095.0*digital_result;
I got a 15.9v result, where am I wrong? it is 12 bit ADC and single-ended

Comment: @adam - Thanks for adding the solution :-) However on Stack Exchange sites, in this case the correct approach is to write your own answer in the "Your Answer" box, not add it to the question. After writing your answer (perhaps with a system-enforced delay of up to 48 hrs) please "accept" your answer ("green tick") if no-one else has added an even more helpful answer. Without an accepted answer, the website back-end systems will believe that the question is still open and nag us in future to answer it! Writing an answer also makes it easier for future readers to find your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

1. There is a stupid bug mess up the channel configuration. When I switch the channel, I use ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig and did not initialize all parameters of sConfig except for the channel number.
2. We found we have to use 3.3v (by guess) as the ref volt, v=digital_result/4096*3.3v
3. Also, for the calibration we need to enable Verfint Channel in MX

   ```
   HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED); 
   HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1); 
   HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100); 
   int digital_result = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); 
   HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1)
   ```